# How to pass handle_unknown='ignore' to the trained one hot encoder of sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I use `onehotencoder.pkl` file in order to decode new data as follows:

```
my_encoder = joblib.load('onehotencoder.pkl')
X = pd.DataFrame(my_encoder.transform(X).toarray())
```

However, new data include some unseen values. I know that these values can be ignored using `handle_unknown='ignore'`, however how can I pass this parameter in my case? How can I properly handle such cases in order to avoid runtime errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start with something similar to this

```
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>,
       handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=True)
```

Now do

```
my_encoder.handle_unknown = 'ignore'
```

And you'll get

```
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>,
       handle_unknown='ignore', n_values='auto', sparse=True)
```